# Как заставить выполнять код по нажатию клавиши?

Tags: c++

У меня есть бесконечный цикл for внутри него выполняется действия, например какой то вычисления.
По сколько это вычисление долгое, я могу запустить комп на 1 день если он находит результат он мне выдает
**cout << array_result** ответ в консоль.

Это бывает очень редко поэтому консоль не заполняется мусором.

```
for(;;) {
 // код
 // Я что то СЧИТАЮ блаблабла .... :)

 if (result == 2415252151252) {
  cout << " array_result[0] " << array_result[0] << "\n" << endl;
 }

}
```

но иногда мне интересно посмотреть сразу все, каждое действие в цикле и вывести это в консоль.

это выглядело бы вот так

```
for(;;) {
 // код
 // Я что то СЧИТАЮ блаблабла .... :)

 if (result == 2415252151252) {
  cout << " array_result[0] = TEST1 " << array_result[0] << "\n" << endl;
 }

  cout << " array_result[0] " << array_result[0] << "\n" << endl;
}
```

как вы видите `cout <<` находиться снаружи без условий и выдает результат постоянно.
Как раз мне это нужно но не постоянно а по нажатию клавиши и так же с возможностью отключения.
Дело в том что когда `cout <<` работает постоянно он замедляет скорость кода, (ЦИКЛА) и код в разы медленней чем без него.

Еще он не всегда нужен иногда много разных `cout` засоряют консоль, намного удобней если я создам разные условия по кнопкам, например мне нужен массив array1 я нажимаю кнопку **W** получаю `cout`, нажимаю кнопку **W** снова `cout` отключается.
Возможно ли так сделать?

Еще я использую `system("pause");` его наверно лучше будет отключить или можно как то с ним тоже это делать?

`system("pause");` срабатывает потому что цикл находиться в многопоточности и он не как не влияет на `main`
Если я нажимаю любую кнопку вся программа отключается разом, и не важно что там выполняется.

Comment: Ну, например, в том же цикле смотреть, не нажата ли клавиша, и если нажата - считать, какая именно и обработать. Или цикл чтения клавиш в другом потоке, обработка, выставление флага, который проверяется при выводе...

Comment: @Harry а как это записать что я нажал клавишу, или отключил ее нажав снова?

Comment: Ну, если использовать `<conio.h>`, скажем - то типа `if (kbhit() && getch()=='W') out = !out;`, а в выводе - `if (out) cout << ...`. Примерно так.

Comment: @Harry а есть решение что бы `system("pause");` отключился по определенной кнопки?
А то сейчас любое нажатие вызывает срабатывания и `system("pause");` отключается.

Comment: Возможно я все неправильно делаю и есть целый функционал работы с консолью.
Но я точно не знаю и не видел этот функционал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что у меня получилось. Наверное, не самый лучший способ, но работает)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int key;
    bool out = true;
    long long int result = 0;
    int array_result[100] = {};
    for(;;) {
        keybd_event(13, 0,0,0);
        keybd_event(13, 0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0); //имитирует нажатие Enter
        key = _getch(); //получает данные о нажатой клавише, останавливает программу, если клавиша не нажата.
        //Поэтому имитируется нажатие Enter
     // код
     // Я что то СЧИТАЮ блаблабла .... :)

     if (result == 2415252151252) {
      cout << " array_result[0] = TEST1 " << array_result[0] << "\n" << endl;
     }

     if (out == true and key != 'w'){ //out хранит данные о том, включён ли вывод, key - о нажатой клавише
         cout << " array_result[0] " << array_result[0] << "\n" << endl;
     }

     if (key == 'w'){out = !out;} //при нажатии w - out инвертируется

    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо буду дома гляну.